# Filter data on array

Tags: java

I'm trying to filter the userId, name and the age of the user using (>, <, =) operators.
I kinda got stuck because I always do this via SQL but in the case I already have the data in a List.

The array has about 1 Million Users but after filtering I will use pagination so don't worry about the size of the filtered array

Any guidance on how to implement this in a fast way? Is it possible to use the operator on the Collection?

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity << ? > getUsers(@RequestParam Long userId, @RequestParam Integer age, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "=") String operator) {

  List < User > data = userService.getData();

  data.stream().filter( ? ? );


  return new ResponseEntity < > (data, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: You are expected to do serious research prior posting a question here. The internet is full of tutorials that tell you how to use streams and filters, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-filter-lambda for example.

Comment: @GhostCat I know how to filter but I don't know how to use the operator

Comment: In your case, you probably first want to get the "filtering" for each of your potential search values right, then you look out what it means to combine them. And well, for 1 million users, it might be absolutely worth to figure if you can change your design and have your data source do that query for you.

Comment: @GhostCat it's not a design, it's just an exercise

Comment: Well, you have to provide a lambda that uses the operators, depending on the type. The link I have you has examples.

Comment: It's not clear what your filter criteria are. You write that you want to filter by [`User`] name, but what names do you want to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own process by using if..else or switch..case, of better you create a map with all action needed like this:

```
Map<String, Predicate<User>> actions = new HashMap<>();
actions.put("=", u -> u.getId() == userId); // or any condition you want
actions.put("<", u -> u.getId() < userId);
actions.put(">", u -> u.getId() > userId);

// You can also check and if not exist throw an exception
Predicate<User> action = actions.getOrDefault(operator, actions.get("="));


data.stream()
        .filter(action::test) // <------- apply the action.
        ..
```

Or simply as @MarkRotteveel mention, you can simply use action without test:

```
data.stream()
        .filter(action)
```

Comment: Hi @YCF_L thanks for helping. What is the :: test?

Comment: @TiagoSilva [Predicate::test](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-) it used to execute the Predicate action, for example if the user enter `=` the the filter behind the scene will be `.filter(u -> u.getId() == userId)`

Comment: Any idea how to simplify the actions? Because I will need to create 3 actions for each field. Imagine I have 10 different filters, I will need to manually create 30 predicate actions

Comment: @TiagoSilva you can do any action in the right part of lambda, the objectif is to just return a boolean from action, for example `actions.put("<", u -> u.getId() < userId && u.getAge < age);` and so on

Comment: The filter code can be simplified to `filter(action)`. `action` is already a predicate, so there is no need to derive a new predicate from the `test` method of `action`.

Comment: Exactly, thank you @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

To comparing age you can use this simple function below:

```
private boolean compareAge(String operator, Integer ageToCompare, Integer age) {
    return switch (operator) {
        case "<" -> ageToCompare < age;
        case ">" -> ageToCompare > age;
        default -> ageToCompare.equals(age);
    };
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to do that for each field

Comment: Would you like to compare by operator only age and userId?